Create a single docker image that contains both for angular app frontend and backend .NET 8 API
I have two applications:

frontend application built on angular framework (call it as frontend)
.NET 8 API with target runtime linux-x64. (call it as backend). It is also a self contained backend api.

I have a requirement to create one single docker image that contains both frontend and backend and should be able to serve them as well. I should be able to browse both frontend and backend with some url like:

http://localhost:2222/ (frontend)
http://localhost:2222/swagger/index.html (backend api)

Is it possible to achieve this?
I know that this is not a recommended way and not what docker is supposed to do. But this is kind of my projects requirement.

Yes, it's possible. Even easy. You can use Kestrel to serve static content like your frontend application. Look here for more information.

I saw this post earlier. It seems complex and there is not suggestions on how a dockerfile should look like @HansKilian

@devatwork the docker file will look essentially the same.

You add UseStaticFiles to your ASP.NET pipeline as shown in the link I posted. Then place your frontend files in a wwwroot directory in the final image along with your API and that should be it.
